# How can Windows API calls to an application/service be monitored?

Tags: winapi, monitoring

My company is looking at implementing a new VPN solution, but require that the connection be maintained programatically by our software. The VPN solution consists of a background service that seems to manage the physical connection and a command line/GUI utilty that initiates the request to connect/disconnect. I am looking for a way to "spy" on the API calls between the front-end utilty and back-end service so that our software can make the same calls to the service. Are there any recommended software solutions or methods to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Typically, communications between a front-end application and back-end service are done through some form of IPC (sockets, named pipes, etc.) or through custom messages sent through the Service Control Manager. You'll probably need to find out which method this solution uses, and work from there - though if it's encrypted communication over a socket, this could be difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Like Harper Shelby said, it could be very difficult, but you may start with [filemon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896642.aspx), which can tell you when certain processes create or write to files, [regmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896652.aspx), which can do the same for registry writes and reads, and [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to monitor the network traffic. This can get you some data, but even with the data, it may be too difficult to interpret in a manner that would allow you to make the same calls.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you want to replace the utility, instead of simply running the utility from your application.

Anyway, you can run "dumpbin /imports *whatevertheutilitynameis*.exe" to see the static list of API function names to which the utility is linked; this doesn't show the sequence in which they're called, nor the parameter values.

You can then use a system debugger (e.g. Winice or whatever its more modern equivalent might be) to set breakpoints on these API, so that you break into the debugger (and can then inspect parameter values) when the utility invokes these APIs.

Comment: Agreed; there are many reasons *not* to reverse-engineer the protocol and implement one side of it yourself...

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to glean some information using tools such as [Spy++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242713(VS.60).aspx) to look at Windows messages.  Debugging/tracing tools ([Windbg](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/default.mspx), or etc.) may allow you to see API calls that are in process.  The [Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/default.aspx) tools can show you system information to some degree of detail of usage.

Although I would recommend against this for the most part -- is it possible to contact the solution provider and get documentation?  One reason for that is fragility -- if a vendor is not expecting users to utilize that aspect of the interface, they are more likely to change it without notice.